# UWP-Windows Hello maximum no of fingerprint attempts

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop-application, fingerprint, windows-hello

I have integrated fingerprint authentication into my UWP app. I want to give maximum fingerprint attempts to the user. If the user exceeds the attempts I want to provide a message asking to re-login using the password. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Any updates for this thread ?

Answer (score 0):

> UWP-Windows Hello maximum no of fingerprint attempts

Currently, there is no such api for setting  maximum fingerprint attempts, it was handle internal by [`UserConsentVerifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.ui.userconsentverifier?view=winrt-22621). If you do want to edit this parameter please feel free post your requirement with windows feedback hub app.

> I want to provide a message asking to re-login using the password

Please check [Request consent and return results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/fingerprint-biometrics#request-consent-and-return-results) document, you could show a dialog when it turn into `RetriesExhausted` state that *have been too many failed attempts*.